# VBA: Custom Right Click Menu Option Isn't Visible

Tags: vba, controls, user-defined-functions, commandbar

I am trying to create an option that allows the user to remove data validation from a cell via the right click menu option. So far, the code is compiling and executing without errors. It is succesfully adding the custom control to the collection Commandbars("cell").Controls. It also has the correct tag and the correct OnAction value. But for some reason it is not appearing in the right click menu. I copied and pasted this code from another project I did, and it still runs fine in the other excel workbook. All I changed was the caption and the OnAction strings. I am baffled by this. Any help is greatly appreciated. Code below.

[EDIT]: I am debugging and I added a watch across all modules and procedures for Application.CommandBars("cell").Controls.Count and for some incredible reason, simply adding another identical watch to the list, for Application.CommandBars("cell").Controls.Count, in break mode, caused the count to increase by 1.

The count also goes up by one each time I press F8 to step to the next line, even when an error is thrown due to the objControl object not being initialized for some reason. See screenshot below to see what I saw during debugging. The highlighted yellow line is throwing an error for an object that hasn't been initialized yet, and each time I try to execute that line, the Count increases by 1.

[EDIT 2]: Apparently adding a watch for literally anything, even while in break mode, causes the count to increase by 1. I have no idea how or why.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeRightClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
Dim objControl As Object, sum As Double, vCell As Variant, fieldtype As Integer
Dim tagArr() As String, i As Integer
If Target.Count > 1 And Target.MergeCells = False Then GoTo lbl_Exit
If Intersect(Target, Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation)) Is Nothing 
Then GoTo lbl_Exit
ReDim tagArr(0)
tagArr(0) = "brccm"
i = 0
For i = 0 To UBound(tagArr)
    For Each objControl In Application.CommandBars("cell").Controls
        If objControl.Tag = "" Then objControl.Delete
        If tagArr(i) = objControl.Tag Then
            objControl.Delete
            GoTo lbl_Deleted
        End If
lbl_Next:
    Next objControl
lbl_Deleted:
Next i
i = 0
If Target.row < 83 And Target.Column < 14 Then 'the active area for the order form
    'If Not Intersect(ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation), Target) Is Nothing Then 'if cell has any validation settings at all
        capture_target_range Target
        'For i = 0 To UBound(tagArr)
        With Application.CommandBars("cell").Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton, before:=1, temporary:=True)
            .Tag = tagArr(0)
            .Caption = "Clear data validation restrictions from cell"
            .OnAction = "'RightClick_ClearValidation'"
        End With
End If
Exit Sub
lbl_Exit:
On Error Resume Next
i = 0
For Each objControl In Application.CommandBars("cell").Controls
    For i = 0 To UBound(tagArr)
        If objControl.Tag = tagArr(i) Then objControl.Delete
    Next i
Next objControl
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Is the cell that you're attempting click in a row less than 83 and in a column less than 14?

Comment: Yes. I am clicking cell C8, which has data validation list = Yes, No. I have stepped through the code and it goes all the way down into that if block, adds the control, the caption, and the OnAction properties without an issue

Comment: The problem is that that there are **two** CELL menus: 1) in Normal layout and 2) Page layout. Switching to either layout affects menu visibility.

Comment: I was using the page break view in this worksheet. How do I know which cell menu I'm dealing with? Do they have different scopes? Even stranger, now I am debugging and I added a watch across all modules and procedures for Application.CommandBars("cell").Controls.Count and for some incredible reason, simply adding another watch to the list for Application.CommandBars("cell").Controls.Count while in break mode caused the count to increase by 1. The count also goes up by one each time I press F8 to step to the next line, even when an error is thrown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that that there are two CELL menus: 1) in Normal layout and 2) Page layout. Switching to either layout affects menu visibility - this means that if you create menu in Normal layout, you won't see it in Page layout - and vice versa.

You can ensure that there are two CELL menus by running the following code:

```
Sub ListCommandBars()
    Dim r%, cmb As CommandBar
    For Each cmb In CommandBars
        r = r + 1
        Cells(r, 1) = cmb.Name
    Next
    [A1].CurrentRegion.Sort Key1:=[A1]
End Sub
```

To differentiate one from another, you can use their `Index` property which returns internal number. The real problem is that these numbers are different from version to version. I advise you to add your menu in both layouts. For it you need to iterate over all command bars filtering CELL menu:

```
Sub AddMenu2()
    Dim cmb As CommandBar
    For Each cmb In CommandBars
        If cmb.Name = "Cell" Then
            '// Add your menu here
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: That solved it. Thank you for the insight! I had no idea there were two menus. Although this still does not explain why I was seeing variables' properties change every time I added a watch to the list. Never seen anything like that in my life